# How can I assign a variable value of onclick function in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, selector

Basically, I would like a specific div section to display (show) it's content once an anchor is clicked. That section must only display the content if it's element title matches with the button title.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="#accordion" id="my-link" class="btn btn-primary">Open group 2</a>
<br/>
<a href="#accordion" id="my-link2" class="btn btn-primary">Communications</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Section with the title of "Communications" in the div element
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" title="Communications">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Normally, it works fine with this script:

```
$('#my-link2').click(function(e) {
    var currentAnchor = $(this);
    alert(currentAnchor.text());
    $("[title*='Communications']").collapse('show');
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');        
});
```

But when using the line of codes below, it doesnt seems to work:

```
$('#my-link2').click(function(e) {
    var currentAnchor = $(this);
    alert(currentAnchor.text());
    $("[title*='" + currentAnchor() + "']").collapse('show'); <-- I think i'm doing something wrong here
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');        
});
```

To test it, please refer to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/DSGxz/632/ and just change the HTML, and script, with the above samples.

Thank you in advance, appreciate any help that i could get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checkout your browser's JS Console you will see the following error:

[image]

Try instead to use the inner text of the element:

```js
$('#my-link2').click(function(e) {
    var currentAnchor = $(this);
    alert(currentAnchor.text());
    $("[title*='" + currentAnchor.text() + "']").collapse('show');
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With some minor modifications to the buttons , adding a class and a data attribute, you could do a more generic listener for the whole class of buttons.

Something like:

HTML

```
<a href="#accordion" id="my-link" data-panel="2" class="btn btn-primary mytoggle-btn">Open group 2</a>
```

JS

```
$('.mytoggle-btn').click(function(e) {
    var $panel = $('#panel' + $(this).data('panel')),
        $content = $panel.find('.panel-collapse');
    // collapse other panels
    $('#accordion .panel-collapse').not($content).collapse('hide');
    // show the associated on to this button instance        
    $content.collapse('show');        
});
```